# can't open modal if once it is closed

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem if I open modal and close it then I can't open again it, I must refresh first.

```
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_id ORDER BY video_id ASC") or trigger_error("Päringu viga: " . mysqli_error($con));

  while($video = mysqli_fetch_array($db)) 
  { 
    $sona1 = preg_split( '/ |-/', $video['video_nimi']);
    //$sona1 = str_word_count($video['video_nimi'], 1);
?>
<article class="grid_4 thumbnail-1">
    <h3><span><?php echo $sona1[0]; ?></span> <?php echo $sona1[1]; ?> </h3>
    <figure class="box-img">
      <a href="#<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>">
    <center> <img src="<?php echo $kohvik['installation_path'] . 'systeem/timthumb.php?src=' . $kohvik['installation_path'] . $video['video_pilt'] . '&h=146&w=280&zc=1'; ?>" style="z-index:1; position: absolute;" height="146" width="280"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9Tp/enR/9TpenRLTE.svg" style="z-index:2; position: relative;" height="146" width="280"> </center>
    </a>
    </figure><a href="#_" onclick="stop();" class="lightbox" id="<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>">
      <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close full-height" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="stop();" id="sule">X</button>
        <h3><?php echo $video['video_nimi']; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><iframe id="test_<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $video['video_link']; ?>&rel=0" width="870" height="489" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
  </div>
 </a>
</article>
<script>
function stop(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('test_<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
}
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

But I can open another modal and if I close also that modal then cant open both must refresh.

Comment: If there is many rows fetched from data then may be using same id like `videoModal` would be the problem

Comment: What is your question? Please be specific about your problem and what you need to solve it. Nobody will just try to fix your code if you don't ask for anything specific. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: problem is that, first modal works perfectly it stops video and can reopen but next video modal doesnt stop.